# Scanning an NSArray to produce an NSSet

Tags: objective-c

I have an `NSArray` called `program` and I need to scan it and then produce an `NSSet` of objects that fit the test `isOperation:`.  If none are found I should return `nil`.  I wrote the following code.  How would you make this better? (FYI - the fact the program is of type (id) comes directly from the assignment so I can't change that one thing)

Revised code:

```
+ (NSSet *) variablesUsedInProgram:(id)program {
    NSSet *programSet, *variablesUsed;
    if([program isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {
        programSet = [NSSet setWithArray:program];
        variablesUsed = [programSet objectsPassingTest:^BOOL(id term, BOOL *stop) {
            return (! ([term isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class]] || [CalculatorBrain isOperation:term]));  
        }];
    }
    return ([variablesUsed count] > 0) ? variablesUsed : nil;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to return a copy of the variablesUsed set. It's actually wrong to do so, because naming conventions for your method imply an autoreleased object to be returned. Thus I would rewrite your return as:

```
return [variablesUsed autorelease];
// or in case of ARC just
return variablesUsed;
```

See the [Advanced memory management programming guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html)

Also set contains a useful method to filter using a block. In my opinion this results in slightly nicer code. You can convert your incoming array to a `NSSet` using `+ setWithArray:`.

The if statement to return nil can be combined in your return.

Combining this results in the following implementation

```
+ (NSSet *) variablesUsedInProgram:(id)program {
    NSSet *programSet = [NSSet setWithArray:program];
    NSSet *variablesUsed = [NSSet objectsPassingTest:^(id object, BOOL *stop) {
        return !([object isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class]] || [self isOperation:term])
    }];
    return ([variablesUsed count] > 0) ? variablesUsed : nil;
}
```

Comment: Thank you - this is a very nice solution.  By the way, I have two questions:

Comment: 1. What is "BOOL *stop"  used for? and

Comment: 2. Why is it wrong to return a copy of variablesUsed?

Comment: Incidentally, I am using ARC - should I be calling release in any situation?  I was under the impression that it is reserved for the compiler under ARC.

Comment: 1. "The block can set the value to YES to stop further processing of the set." - see [the NSSet documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSSet_Class/Reference/Reference.html). Not needed in your case.

Comment: 2. You can still return a copy if you really want to, but the naming convention dictates an autoreleased object. A copy is actually owned. ARC will actually add an autorelease to your statement: [[variablesUsed copy] autorelease] to make up for the ownership. Even when you are using ARC, it's good to take the naming conventions into account, because ARC uses them too. See the documents I linked in the answer for more on those conventions.

Comment: No need to call release yourself when using ARC, just understand what's going and what ARC is actually doing.

Comment: In the end, I had some difficulty implementing this solution - can you think of a way to cast the terms as NSString* before adding them to the set I return?

Comment: There's no need to. The `(NSString *)` cast in your original example code has no meaning, it would even work when the actual object was of a different type. A set accepts an `id` type, so it doesn't matter what object is added.

Comment: Your right - I made a mistake in typing my test condition.  It works now.  Thank you!  I'm still curious, however - do you know of a way to do a transformation (using built-in functions like objectsPassingTest etc.) as a last step before adding the object to the set as vikingosegundo's List Comprehensions-based solution below lets you do?

Answer (score 2):

I want to propose something similar to the answer Joris gave.

Inspired by [List Comprehensions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_comprehension)

```
python: l = [i**2 for i in l if i%2] #filtes a list for all even numbers and squares them
```

I wrote a number of category methods on NSArray to be able to do something similar using Blocks.

here one that fits to your needs:

*interface*

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface NSArray (FunctionalTools)

-(NSSet *)setByPerformingBlock:(id  (^)(id element))performBlock
           ifElementPassesTest:(BOOL (^)(id element))testBlock;

@end
```

*implementation*

```
@implementation NSArray (FunctionalTools)

-(NSSet *)setByPerformingBlock:(id   (^)(id))performBlock 
           ifElementPassesTest:(BOOL (^)(id))testBlock
{
    NSMutableSet *set = [NSMutableSet setWithArray:self];
    NSMutableSet *newSet = [NSMutableSet set];
    for (id element in set){
        if (testBlock(element)) {
            [newSet addObject:performBlock(element)];
        }
    }
    if ([newSet count]<1)
        return nil;
    return [NSSet setWithSet:newSet];
}
@end
```

*usage*

```
+ (NSSet *) variablesUsedInProgram:(id)program {
     return [program setByPerformingBlock:^id(id term) {
        return term;
     } ifElementPassesTest:^BOOL(id term) {
        return !([term isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class]] || [self isOperation:term]);
     }];
```

Comment: Cool! :)  I like this technique... any downsides?

Comment: I don't like `return [NSSet setWithSet:newSet];`, but I think, it is better, to not surprise the programmer by returning a mutable set.

Comment: In the implementation why are you creating an NSMutableSet out of the array (self) just to turn it back into an array in the for statement?

Comment: I am creating a set to avoid that possibly expensive blocks are executed more often than needed. `[set allObjects]`was a copy and past error.

Comment: I disagree that it's at all important to care whether your set is mutable or not. Your return type is `NSSet*`, so if the programmer even finds out that your set is mutable, they already messed up bigtime.

Answer (score 0):

The only real issue I see is that you're leaking memory. You are allocating a mutable set that you never release and then copying it to presumably make it immutable thus leaking more memory.

```
+ (NSSet *) variablesUsedInProgram:(id)program {
    NSMutableSet *variablesUsed = [[NSMutableSet alloc] init];
    for (id term in program) {
        if(! ([term isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class]] || 
              [self isOperation:term])) {
            /* term is a variable, because it's neither an operation or a number */
            [variablesUsed addObject:(NSString *)term];

        }
    }
    NSSet returnSet = nil;
    if (variablesUsed.count > 0) {
        returnSet = [NSSet setWithSetVariableSet];
    }
    [variablesUsed release];
    return returnSet;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your newer version, if `program` is not an NSArray then `variablesUsed` is uninitialized. Set it to nil where you declare it.

Remember to always check failure paths in conditional statements.

Also you should start using Xcode's *Build and Analyze* option to get the LLVM compiler to point out these kinds of errors.